# Ubuntu will not get latest version from PPA

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

**NOTE:** I know that I am using 15.10, an EOL release, but I am developing the PPA on 15.10, and all packages are for it. This also isn't affecting any other PPAs or packages, and I think it is not related to my release.

---

I have created a PPA for my Ubuntu 15.10 system.
I added it and updated like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nann-sahibdeep/inverse-ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

After some testing, turns out the first version, `4.1-0ubuntu1` had a packaging error, so I made a new package, `4.1-1ubuntu1`.

Launchpad confirms I have uploaded it to the PPA. But, the problem arises when I try and install it.

```
sudo apt-get install inverse-dev
```

It's trying to fetch `4.1-0` and not `4.1-1`, which is why the install fails.

**Is there any reason that Ubuntu is not getting the latest version on the PPA?**

Comment: It's not completely published yet. Just be patient. :)

Comment: It can take up to an hour (when behind the scenes cleanup happens or other issues) for the publisher on Launchpad to take newly completed builds and make it available on `ppa.launchpad.net` - usually within 20 minutes it gets published but it can take time.  If the packages just finished building then wait up to an hour for the uploader system on the backend to catch up and push your builds to the actual PPA repo server